# emacs make-frame does not show the frame on the current display until restored

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am having trouble.  I want to press <kbd>F11</kbd> and have Emacs create a new frame, then set its size, then launch `gnus`.  During this I want it to bring the new frame to the front.  I can't seem to figure that last part out.  Here is my code minus the bring-to-front part:

```
(defun launch_gnus_new_frame ()
  "Open a new frame and then launch gnus"
  (interactive)
  (let* (new_frame_gnus (new-frame))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-frame new_frame_gnus)
    (if window-system
        (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 101 90))
    (gnus)))

(global-set-key [f11] 'launch_gnus_new_frame)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT**: Here is my current code.

```
(defun launch_gnus_new_frame ()
  "Open a new frame and then launch gnus"
  (interactive)
  (let ((gmail_frame (make-frame '((name . "gmail") (window-system . x)))))
    (select-frame-set-input-focus gmail_frame)
    (if window-system
        (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 101 90))
    (gnus)))

(global-set-key [f11] 'launch_gnus_new_frame)
```

I have determined that the new frame has been created and my point is in the new buffer running `gnus`. However, the frame is not on my display until I minimize and restore it.  If I run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `make-frame` I get the same behavior.  I am running Linux Mint with the Cinnamon desktop.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Debian with Fluxbox - I get the new window, and it pops to the front when called as desired. So I think the issue is not with Emacs, but maybe something with the cinnamon desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `x-focus-frame` function.

```
(when (fboundp 'x-focus-frame)
  (x-focus-frame nil))
```